# SQL: expading "in (...)" to "like"

Tags: sql

I have a sql select like below:

```
select * from table1 where text in (select text from table2)
```

In real in *in clausule* is more complex select that this. `text` is string (varchar). How to expand that sql to select rows from `table1` where `text` **is like** texts from `table2` (not only exactly equals) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your wild card expressions in the text column in Table2 you can do like this.

```
select *
from Table1 as T1
where exists (select *
              from Table2 as T2
              where T1.[text] like T2.[text])
```

Otherwise you need to add the `%` in your query.

```
select *
from Table1 as T1
where exists (select *
              from Table2 as T2
              where T1.[text] like '%'+T2.[text]+'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select * 
from table1 
where exists 
  (
    select *
    from table2 
    where table1.text like N'%'+table2.text+N'%' 
  )
```

**Note**

This may be a performance killer

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party here, but you can also just do this with a JOIN if you need the wildcard text as part of the query (as I did).  Assuming you have all the entries to check against in table2.text,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.text LIKE '%' + t2.text + '%'
```