# How do I search for multiple values in a column where I need to use wildcards?

Tags: sql-server, select

In SQL Server, I need to search a column for multiple values, but I don't have the exact values, so I need to use wildcards as well.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fieldname in ( '%abc1234%',
                     '%cde456%',
                     '%efg8976%')
```

This doesn't return any results, and yet if I search for any one individual value, I find it, so I know they're in there.  Short of doing multiple OR's, which is a bit unwieldy with several hundred values, is there a way to do this?

I'd also be interested to know why this query doesn't work, since the same query without the %'s works just fine (except for the small problem of only catching the few exact matches).

Comment: It doesn't work because `in` uses the `=` operator, and wildcards only work with the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832182/sql-expading-in-to-like) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335359/is-it-possible-to-use-like-and-in-for-a-where-statment) (among others)

Comment: Ah, I get it now.  Judge Mental's second link has a nice answer that explains why it didn't work.  One less misconception I will fall prey to!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get out of enumerating the "several hundred values" in some form or another.

Answer (score 17):

Look at using a [Fulltext Index](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/). That should do a much better job with your search, and make your "OR" problem a *little* nicer to boot:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE CONTAINS(fieldname, '"abc1234" OR "cde456" OR "efg8976"')
```

See also:

> http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/full-text-indexing-workbench/

Comment: Thanks.  I think if I have to do this again with more values, I'll look into an index.  In this case, I looked at the number of values I had, decided that at this time of night, it wasn't enough to cause trouble and did a series of LIKE statements joined by ORs.  It did what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the query doesn't work is that it looks for an exact match for `fieldname` within the list of values in the parens.  It doen't do a `LIKE` comparison where the wildcards are taken into account.

So your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *  from table  
where  fieldname  = '%abc1234%' OR
       fieldname  = '%cde456%' OR        
       fieldname  = '%efg8976%'
```

Obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
select table.* from (
    table join
    ( select * from values (
        ( '%abc1234%' ), ( '%cde456%' ), ( '%efg8976%' )
    ) ) as search( exp ) on 0 = 0
) where fieldname like exp
```

or perhaps

```
select table.* from
    table join
    ( select * from values (
        ( '%abc1234%' ), ( '%cde456%' ), ( '%efg8976%' )
    ) ) as search( exp )
 on fieldname like exp
```

modulo some syntax I'm sure.

The point being that this comes close to allowing the list of values to be the only parameter.